# Optimization of Light transmission

Tags: calculus, optimization

> A window is in the form of a rectangle surmounted by a semicircle.
>
> The rectangle is made of clear glass, whereas the semicircle is of
> tinted glass that transmits only half as much light per unit area as
> the clear glass does. The total perimeter is fixed.
>
> Find the proportions of the window that will admit the most light. Neglect that
> thickness of the frame.

I realize that the total light will be equal to how much light the surface transmits times the amount of area.

If you call the base of the rectangle $x$, height $y$, and the light transmitted by clear glass $L$ you can say that total light is equal to
$$x\cdot y\cdot L + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\pi\cdot x^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}L$$

This seems like too many variable for an optimization problem.  How should I proceed?

Comment: Fun fact: such a window is called a Norman window. A few comments: First, if the width of the rectangle is $x$, then the radius of the circle is $x/2$. Next, you are looking for the proportions that maximize the light transmitted. That means you are looking for a ratio $x/y$. In other words, without loss of generality assume that $x$ has length 1, and that $y=kx=k\cdot 1$ where you are now optimizing over $k$.

Comment: Even if you don't make the nice observation of Alex, you are told that the perimeter is given. Call it $P$, a constant. Then $x+2y+\frac{\pi}{2}x=P$, so you only have one "free" variable.